# Find the coefficient of a^8b^9 in the expansion of (3a + 2b)^13

Tags: discrete-mathematics

i remember doing this in high school but cant remember exactly how to do it.
i believe it uses pascals triangle to expand the term. 
the power of a would start at 13 and decrease to 0 and the power of b would start at 0 and increase to 13, if i remember correctly. 
Just looking for some help on exactly how to do it really.

Comment: you raise $3a+2b$ to the power 13 but you ask for the coefficient of the 17th power... so it should be 0

Comment: That is, in all terms the exponents of $a$ and $b$ must add up to $13$.